# How can this DAO abstract method work without implementation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, model-view-controller

I have a interface DAO class method that extends CrudRep working without implementation. It is a MVC project with Spring Framework and Hibernate ORM. Here is class:

```
package eu.execom.collections.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import eu.execom.collections.model.Book;
import eu.execom.collections.model.User;

public interface BookDAO extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

    public List<Book> findByUser(User user);

}
```

Comment: Proxies. They do everything.

Comment: Proxies and naming convention is important. Spring runs some kind of reflection to find out the methods available, here it sees findByUser; findbBy means 'get' and 'User' is the Entity name. Spring creates an implementation for you internally at run time and binds it to the interface.

Comment: It isn't Spring is is Spring Data JPA that does that.